# Difference between hiding a div initially and hiding it dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have a div that contains a pie chart, which shows the distribution of a particular statistic among cities. That was a bit unnecessary.

I want to show that pie only when **Location** is selected in my drop-down menu. But when I initially hide it and load it again, it doesn't fit to the div and overflows.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nS5wp/1/)

```
$("#pie").hide(); // this line will be removed in second example
```

But when I initially show it and then hide and show again, there is no problem.

[second fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nS5wp/2/)

It is very annoying and I don't have any idea about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hide #pie after .highcharts

```
$(function(){
    $("#pie").highcharts({    
         //...
    });    
    $("#pie").hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nS5wp/5/

Answer (score 1):

You need to give `#pie` a specific width, because highcharts is designed to fill the space it has.

```css
#pie {
    width: 300px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/nS5wp/4/)

Comment: But there is no problem while showing it initially, it just fits perfectly without that line of code.